# Get difference of two date in user friendly format using php

Tags: php, datetime, date-difference

So I'm trying to work out the length of time till a **Date Time** is reached in a user-friendly way.

For example, say the current date time is `2018-09-10 12:00:00` and the end goal is `2019-11-10 12:00:00` I want to simply echo *1 Year*, or say it's `2018-09-10 13:30:00` echo *1 hour* if the time is under a minute just say 1 minute.

I'm really struggling to find any resource describing how to easily do this without a shit ton of if statements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class to converting date string to php object. Then use 
[`DateTime::diff()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) method to get difference of two dates. Also you need to check value of `year`, `month`, `day`, `hour`, `minute` and `second` to return expected result.

```
$sDate = "2018-09-10 12:00:00";
$eDate = "2019-11-10 12:00:00";

$startDate = new DateTime($sDate);
$diff = $startDate->diff(new DateTime($eDate));

if ($diff->y > 0) 
    $diffStr = $diff->y." year";
else if ($diff->m > 0) 
    $diffStr = $diff->m." month";
else if ($diff->d > 0) 
    $diffStr = $diff->d." day";
else if ($diff->h > 0) 
    $diffStr = $diff->h." hour";
else if ($diff->i > 0) 
    $diffStr = $diff->i." minute";
else if ($diff->s > 0) 
    $diffStr = $diff->i." second";
else 
    $diffStr = "dates are same";

echo $diffStr;
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/EbZsO)

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest you use [`Carbon`](https://carbon.nesbot.com)'s [`diffForHumans` metod](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-humandiff). Just make your life easier by leveraging all date related operations to `Carbon`.

Answer (score 0):

actually it's quiet easy. If you are using SQL you can use DATEDIFF and format the result with date_format().

If you are just using php you have to create a new DateTime() object out of the two dates. Then you should be able to subtract those two dates using DateInterval().

For example:

```
$date1 = new DateTime($your1stDate);
$date2 = new DateTime($your2ndDate);
$result = $date1->diff($date2);
echo date_format($result,'Y-m-d h:m.s'); // or something like that
```